# R ggplot2 y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I tried to change y-axis scale range.
I used the code to set the y scale:

```
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(value) - 0.05, max(value) + 0.05))
```

where `value` is a numeric column.
I want the y-axis showing from the minimum of `value` minus `0.05` to maximum of `value` plus `0.05` with the breaks of `0.05`.
However, `coord_cartesian()` does not work. Alternatively, I tried `scale_y_continuous(breaks(min(value) - 0.05, max(value) + 0.05, 0.05))`, it does not work either.

How to edit my code?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `expand` argument in your scale?

Comment: I haven't heart that before. Could you explain more on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: original approach used `coord_cartesian`, but to specify breaks will need `scale_y_continuous`.

```
# Making fake data with similar range
mtcars$wt = mtcars$wt/6 + 0.7

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0.05*0:1000,
                     expand = expand_scale(add = 0.06)) # adjust to taste
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ylim()`

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = hp,
           y = mpg,
           color = cyl
           )
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  ylim(min(mtcars$mpg) - 0.05, max(mtcars$mpg) + 0.05)
```

EDIT: I forgot to incorporate the `max(value) + 1` component, which is now included

Comment: Not work as I want. This just limits the y-axis but the labels on y-axis does not show properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(value) - 0.05, max(value) + 0.05, by = 0.05))
```

Comment: `Error in seq(min(value) - 0.05, max(value) + 0.05, by = 0.05) : 
  object 'value' not found`

Comment: It seems that we cannot use column in `scale_y_continuous`

Comment: Did you try to use your table$value?